# How can I ignore a specific file in sub folder by using .gitignore?

Tags: git, commit

There is a big .exe file in a subfolder in my project, my fold tree is like:

```
.
├── folder1
│   └── theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe
├── folder2
│   ├── fileA
│   └── fileB
│———.gitignore
└── ...
```

And at first, I didn't mention that this "theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe" is larger than 100MB so git bash noticed me it.

then, I tried to ignore this .exe file by using .gitignore, my .gitignore file is:

```
/folder1/theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe
```

and before I `git push` again, I used `git rm -r --cached .` , but it is useless...

HELP MEEEEE!thanks!

Comment: Useless because the file is not ignored or because it was already committed and now cannot be pushed?

Comment: because the file is not ignored.

Comment: I tried another way and it works:

git clone a empty repository
git status
git add .
git rm -r --cached folder1/theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe
git commit -m "message"
git push

Comment: Did you already commit that  file before?

Comment: No, I didn't commit it before (to make sure, I git clone a new repository again and only run `git add .` 

but the "theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe" is added again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should ignore it:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
echo "/folder1/theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe">>.gitignore
git rm --cached folder1/theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe
git check-ignore -v -- folder1/theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe
# you should see a .gitignore rule
```

However, that will allow you to create a new commit without that exe.
That will not, however, remove the exe from the past comimts/history of the repository, which will remain huge as a result.

To truly cleanup the repository, [install `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md), and use a path-based filtering

```
git filter-repo  --path folder1/theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe --invert-paths
```

You will need to force push the result though, so make sure any collaborator on that repository is aware of that change (history rewrite).

Comment: Thanks you so much! It works! 

and I realized that I could't ignore theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe before —— it is actually because I had already commit it before...(I realized it when I see no news when I run `git status` under your guidance but it still ignored theBigFileThatIWantToIgnore.exe
So could you help me about how can I ignore a specific file when I have commit it already?
Thank you again!

Comment: @sunmiao The `git rm --czched` + `.gitignore` mentioned at the beginning helps ignoring a file going forward. But for the past commits, you need `git filter-repo`

Comment: Thank you! so `git rm` is for the past `git add` and `git filter-repo` is for the past `git commit`, right?

Comment: @sunmiao "git rm --cached + git commit" is for the *current* (not past) state of the repository, generating a commit from which the file is now ignored. But `git filter-repo` will take care of the past commits. It will delete (not ignore) the large file from the past commits.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now, but if I run below commands:

`git add .` ==> `git commit` ==> `git push` ==> larger than 100mb github error, push failed ==> add a ignore file ==> `git rm --cached` ==> `git add` == `git commit` ==>`git push`==>still larger than 100mb github error.  what should I do?

Comment: @sunmiao You need to filter-repo done locally, to trim and remove the large file from your repo history. Then a `git push --force` should push a *smaller* amount of data, because the executable would have been purged from all past commits.